# JavaScript / HTML5 Games with DB connections?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm comming with some questions about JavaScipt and HTML5.

1. What would you say about making games in HTML5 (with JS), where there will be connection with database - where players scores will be stored (with usage of PHP and MySQL for instance).
2. How about security matters within above topic? Is it possible, to make such thing secure?
3. Is it possible to encrypt JS code, to make someone not to copy/use it in any way instead of online gaming?
4. Is it a good idea, to write such game from scratch, or some kind of HTML5 game framework?

Comment: You could look into WebSockets and Node.js. Point 3 is not possible because the client has to run the code and thus obtains it and you don't know what the client will be doing with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use PHP and MySQL in conjunction with HTML5/JS by using AJAX and json_encode to pass data between javascript and php. Works pretty well so far, just experimenting.

As far as game frameworks, I'm using easeljs right now. It's alright but I've been having sprite animation whike key down issues with it lately.

Answer (score 0):

There exists a couple tools for obfuscating your code (like http://closure-compiler.appspot.com/home) to prevent people from messing with your database or taking your code, but it still could be possible.
I usually make my own game framework and use that for my HTML5 games, but that's entirely up to you

Comment: Well, OK. And what about connection with DB?